# Track each minute in countdown timer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to show a toast message after completion of each minute.I am using the count down timer and show the timer in a text view.Please help me to sort out this problem.Following is my code.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.track_me_mode);
    counter = new MyCount (length,10);
    counter.start();
    }
    });
         public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
        Context mContext;

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
          super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }


        public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerView.setText ( formatTime(millisUntilFinished));


          }

        public void onFinish() {


              }

            }
public String formatTime(long millis) {
    output = "";
    long seconds = millis / 1000;
    long minutes = seconds / 60;
    long hours=minutes/ 60;

    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    hours=hours%60;

    String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
    String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
    String hoursD=String.valueOf(hours);

    System.out.println(minutesD);

    if (seconds < 10)
      secondsD = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10)
      minutesD = "0" + minutes;

    if (hours < 10)
        hoursD = "0" + hours;

    output = hoursD+" : "+minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: You may try AlarmManager class for this, have a look at this [exmple](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html)

Comment: Its fine but I want to do the same work within this code.Can u please help me..

Comment: is that a full code ?

Comment: Yeah Lucifer its a full code.You can run it..

Comment: ok fine, be back in 5 minutes

Comment: Thanks a lot Lucifer!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30048/discussion-between-lucifer-and-deepak-sharma)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, You need to change your code little bit,

1. You need to change your Seconds variable to class level
2. You need to change your interval as follows,

   from `counter = new MyCount (3600000,10);` to `counter = new MyCount (3600000,1000);` because second argument is millisecond.  I have done all the changes in below code,

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity
   {
   TextView timerView;
   Button end,SOS;
   String output;
   MyCount counter;
   int length;

   // Change by Lucifer
   long seconds;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       timerView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_timer_track_me);

         //        counter = new MyCount (3600000,10);
           counter = new MyCount (3600000,1000);
           counter.start();
   }

   public String formatTime(long millis) 
   {
       output = "";
       seconds = millis / 1000;
       long minutes = seconds / 60;
       long hours=minutes/ 60;

       seconds = seconds % 60;
       minutes = minutes % 60;
       hours=hours%60;

       String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
       String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
       String hoursD=String.valueOf(hours);

       if (seconds < 10)
           secondsD = "0" + seconds;
       if (minutes < 10)
           minutesD = "0" + minutes;

       if (hours < 10)
           hoursD = "0" + hours;

       output = hoursD+" : "+minutesD + " : " + secondsD;

       return output;
   }

   public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer 
   {
       Context mContext;

       public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
       {
           super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
       }


       public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) 
       {
           timerView.setText ( formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

           if ( seconds == 0 )
           {
               Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
           }
       }

       public void onFinish() {}

   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy()
   {
       super.onDestroy();
       counter.cancel();
   }
   }
   ```