# CountDownTimer onFinish() crashing when opening a new activity ( after video finished looping)

Tags: android, loops, timer, android-videoview

I am working on this very simple app that plays videos in a loop with a countDowntimer attached to it.
Essentially what I have is the following:

1. I instantiate the VideoView
2. If the user checked for the video to loop (1x or 2x)
3. Then in the countdownTimer's `onFinish()` I wait a few seconds and then start a new activity like such:

   ```
       public void openCompletedWorkout() {

        handler = new Handler();

       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {

               final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompletedWorkoutActivity.class);
               getActivity().startActivity(mainIntent);
               getActivity().finish();
           }

       }, 5000);

   }
   ```

The above method is called inside the `onFinish()` method (of the `CoundDownTimer`).

The problem is if the user doesn't want to have the videoPlayer to loop, everything works fine, meaning, the `onFinish()` function calls the `OpenCompletedWorkout()` method without crashing ( the activity opens with no problem).  However, when the user either says that they want for the video to loop 1x or 2x, when it comes time to call `onFinish()`, the app crashes.

I don't know what's wrong.  I have been trying to fix this issue for the past 4hrs and still having a lot of issues.

Just to put things into perspective,  below is my fragmentActivity where all is happening:

```
public class PlayVideoFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String VIDEO_PATH = "android.resource://";

TextView screenTitle;
TextView textTitle;
String myTime;
String myPlan;
private ImageButton pauseButton;
private ImageButton playButton;
private VideoView videoPlayer;
private MediaController mc;
private TextView counter;
private MediaPlayer soundPlayer;

private int mRepeats;

String output;
MyCounter downCounter;

int length;
long leftTime;
long seconds;

Handler handler;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedStateInstance) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_video_container, container,
            false);

    pauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    playButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    counter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        myTime = bundle.getString("time");
        myPlan = bundle.getString("plan");
    }

    videoPlayer = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);

    if (myPlan.equals("intense")) {

        if (myTime.equals("fiveMin")) {
            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_one, myTime.toString(), 0);

        } else if (myTime.equals("tenMin")) {
            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_one, myTime.toString(), 1);
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LOOOP ONCE!!",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (myTime.equals("fifteenMin")) {
            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_one, myTime.toString(), 2);
        }

        // playVideo(R.raw.abs_workout_one, myTime.toString());

    } else if (myPlan.equals("extreme")) {

        if (myTime.equals("fiveMin")) {
            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_two, myTime.toString(), 0);

        } else if (myTime.equals("tenMin")) {

            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_two, myTime.toString(), 1);

        } else if (myTime.equals("fifteenMin")) {
            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_two, myTime.toString(), 2);
        }

        // playVideo(R.raw.abs_workout_two, myTime.toString());

    } else if (myPlan.equals("insane")) {

        if (myTime.equals("fiveMin")) {
            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_three, myTime.toString(), 0);

        } else if (myTime.equals("tenMin")) {

            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_three, myTime.toString(), 1);

        } else if (myTime.equals("fifteenMin")) {

            playVideoTimed(R.raw.abs_workout_three, myTime.toString(), 2);
        }

        // playVideo(R.raw.abs_workout_three, myTime.toString());

    }

    return v;

}

public void playVideoTimed(int videoPath, String mins, int repeats) {

    long timeElapsed = 0;

    if (mins.equals("fiveMin")) {
        repeats = 0;
        mRepeats = 0;
        timeElapsed = 300000;

    } else if (mins.equals("tenMin")) {
        repeats = 1;
        mRepeats = 1;
        timeElapsed = 600000;

    } else if (mins.equals("fifteenMin")) {
        repeats = 2;
        mRepeats = 2;
        timeElapsed = 900000;
    }
    downCounter = new MyCounter(timeElapsed, 1000);
    downCounter.start();

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VIDEO_PATH + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"
            + videoPath);

    mc = new MediaController(getActivity());
    videoPlayer.setMediaController(null); // used to be mc being passed to
                                            // show controls
    videoPlayer.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoPlayer.requestFocus();
    videoPlayer.start();

    videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            if (mRepeats == 1) {

                mp.setLooping(false);
                mp.seekTo(0);
                mp.start();

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.setLooping(false);
                        //mp.seekTo(0);
                        //mp.stop();
                        try{

                            mp.stop();
                            mp.reset();
                            mp.release();
                            mp = null;


                        }catch(IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                });

            } // end if
            else if (mRepeats == 2) {

                mp.seekTo(0);
                mp.start();

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        try{

                            mp.setLooping(false);
                            mp.seekTo(0);
                            mp.start();

                        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                try{
                                    mp.setLooping(false);
                                    mp.stop();
                                    mp.reset();
                                    mp.release();
                                    mp = null;


                                }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }

                        });

                    }

                });
            }// end final IF

        } // END FUNCTION

    });

}

public void playVideo(int videoPath, String mins) {
    long timeElapsed = 0;

    if (mins.equals("fiveMin")) {
        timeElapsed = 300000;

    } else if (mins.equals("tenMin")) {
        timeElapsed = 600000;

    } else if (mins.equals("fifteenMin")) {
        timeElapsed = 900000;
    }
    downCounter = new MyCounter(timeElapsed, 1000);
    downCounter.start();

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VIDEO_PATH + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"
            + videoPath);

    mc = new MediaController(getActivity());
    videoPlayer.setMediaController(null); // used to be mc being passed to
                                            // show controls
    videoPlayer.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoPlayer.requestFocus();
    videoPlayer.start();

}

public void playDoneSound() {
    soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),
            R.raw.well_done_workout_completed);
    soundPlayer.start();
}

public void killSounds() {
    if (soundPlayer != null) {
        soundPlayer.stop();
        soundPlayer.release();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.pauseButton:
        videoPlayer.pause();
        playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        downCounter.cancel();

        break;

    case R.id.playButton:
        videoPlayer.seekTo(videoPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        videoPlayer.start(); // little hack to get the video to play from
                                // where it stopped

        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        downCounter = new MyCounter(leftTime, 1000);
        downCounter.start();
        // downCounter
        break;

    }

}

// inner class for our timer
/**
 * 
 * @author http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584328/track-each-minute-in-
 *         countdown-timer
 * 
 */

public String formatTime(long millis) {

    output = "";
    seconds = millis / 1000;
    long minutes = seconds / 60;
    long hours = minutes / 60;

    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    hours = hours % 60;

    String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
    String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
    String hoursD = String.valueOf(hours);

    if (hours > 10)
        secondsD = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10)
        minutesD = "0" + minutes;

    if (hours < 10)
        hoursD = "0" + hours;

    if (seconds < 10)
        secondsD = "0" + seconds;

    // output = hoursD+" : " +minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
    output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
    return output;

}

public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer {

    Context mContext;

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        counter.setText("Done!");
        playDoneSound();
        downCounter.cancel();
        downCounter = null;

        //if (mRepeats == 0) {
            openCompletedWorkout();
        //}

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        leftTime = millisUntilFinished;

        counter.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

    }


    public void openCompletedWorkout() {

         handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompletedWorkoutActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(mainIntent);
                getActivity().finish();
            }

        }, 5000);

    }

}
```

}

And here is the logCat:

```
10-14 13:15:29.273: E/MediaPlayer(18712): [MediaPlayer.java:767:setDataSource()] setDataSource() uri: android.resource://com.pocketworkouts.armsworkout/2130968576
```

10-14 13:25:29.669: E/MediaPlayer(18712): [MediaPlayer.java:1198:release()] release()
10-14 13:25:34.874: W/dalvikvm(18712): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712): java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1228)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.widget.VideoView.release(VideoView.java:505)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:49)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceDestroyed(VideoView.java:495)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.SurfaceView.reportSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:596)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:490)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:215)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:4098)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:786)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1863)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:647)
10-14 13:25:34.904: E/AndroidRuntime(18712):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: LogCat printouts even if they don't say much are quite useful to include in your question.

Comment: Just added the logCat. Thanks